# CSS id selector not working for display flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm making a navigation bar as a React component, but for some reason my `display:flex` is not working on an id css selector `#main-nav`. Seems to work if I attach it to a class selector, but I really want it on my id selection.

It keeps using my `display:flex` which is inside my media query even when I expand my window. 
It won't turn into rows for some reason pass 600px. However everything else works as expected.

Is there something about ID CSS selectors I do not know? Cause I thought an ID and lower statements take precedence.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
    min-height: 55px;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(260deg, #2376ae 0%, #c16ecf   100%);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;

}

#main-nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top:24px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#main-nav li {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px auto;
  color: white;

}

.nav-links,
.logo {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.nav-bar-toggle {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  font-size: 24px;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  #main-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

  }

  .nav-bar-toggle {
    visibility: visible;
  }

  .active {
    display: block !important;
  }

  .hidden {
    display: none !important;
  }

}
```

Component render:

```
<nav className="navbar">
      <span className="nav-bar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle" onClick={this.toggleNav} >
        <span className="nav-bar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
          <i className="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </span>
      </span>
        <a href="#" className="logo"></a>
        <ul id="main-nav" className={ this.state.hidden ? 'active' : 'hidden' }></ul>
      { this.props.links ? (
        Object.keys(this.props.links).map(key =>
             <li className={ this.state.hidden ? 'active' : 'hidden' }><a href={ this.props.links[key] } className="nav-links">{ key }</a></li>
          )
      ) : (
          <div></div>
        )
      }
      </nav>
```

Comment: Your `<li>`s are outside of your `<ul>`?

Comment: bingo! dumb mistake on my part. Forgot to complete my code inside after autocomplete!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `ul#main-nav` element is not wrapping your list-items currently:

```
<ul id="main-nav" className={ this.state.hidden ? 'active' : 'hidden' }></ul>
```

Your `ul#main-nav` closing tag (`</ul>`) should be outside of your `li` elements. Because the element is not wrapping the list-items, some of your style, like `list-style-type: none;`, won't work. Neither will any of the style you've defined for `#main-nav li`, since `#main-nav` currently doesn't have any `li` children.